Horror film about a ghost woman dressed in black going after a kid
I'm trying to figure out the title of a horror movie that I watched some time ago, but I can't find it with Google no matter what.
The movie is basically about the ghost of a woman, dressed in black and with her face covered, who wants to abduct/kill (I don't remember) the child of a couple. The woman appears in a few photos of the family, and in each photo she gets closer to the child, and points her finger at him. Also, in a scene near the end of the movie, one of the characters (the father I think) screams at her trying to make her go away, and she attacks him violently.
The movie is not old, I think it's from the 90s or 2000s.

It is Insidious Chapter 1.

A married couple Josh (Patrick Wilson) and Renai (Rose Byrne), their sons Dalton (Ty Simpkins) and Foster (Andrew Astor), and infant daughter Cali have recently moved into a new home. One night, Dalton is drawn to the attic when he hears creaking noises and sees the door open by itself. He falls from a ladder while investigating and sees a figure in the shadows. Hearing his terrified screams, Renai and Josh rush to his aid and declare the attic "off limits" to the children. The next day, Dalton falls into an inexplainable coma.
After three months of treatment without result, Renai and Josh are
  allowed to take Dalton home. Soon after, supernatural activity begins
  to occur; Renai begins hearing voices over the baby monitor when no
  one is in Cali's room, Foster says that Dalton sleepwalks at night,
  Renai sees a frightening figure of a man in Cali's room, who vanishes
  when Josh comes and the burglar alarm is repeatedly triggered for no
  reason with the front door open. After Renai finds a bloody hand print
  on Dalton's bed, she questions Josh about the house, but he ignores
  her. That night, Renai is attacked by the figure from Cali's room, and
  the Lamberts decide to abandon the house and move elsewhere.
In the new house, Renai sees the ghost of a dancing boy who leads her
  to Dalton's room. Josh's mother, Lorraine (Barbara Hershey), visits
  them one day, and says she had a dream in which a figure in Dalton's
  room replies "Dalton" when she asks what it wants; at the same time,
  she sees a monstrous red-faced demon standing behind Josh and screams,
  while Dalton's room is ransacked and Dalton himself is found laying on
  the floor.
Lorraine calls paranormal investigators Elise Reiner (Lin Shaye),
  Specs (Leigh Whannell), and Tucker (Angus Sampson). Upon entering,
  Elise senses a presence in the house and upon entering Dalton's room,
  she sees something on the ceiling; to which Specs draws the demonic,
  red-faced figure Lorraine saw.
Elise explains that Dalton is not in a coma; he was born with the
  ability to travel mentally to the astral plane. He has traveled too
  far and become lost in a realm called "The Further", a place inhabited
  by the tortured souls of the dead. Without his mental presence,
  Dalton's body appears comatose and spirits can use it to enter the
  physical world. Josh is skeptical until he realizes that all of
  Dalton's drawings are of the demonic entity drawn by Specs.
Elise performs a seance to communicate with Dalton, but they contact
  the demon who threatens them before using Dalton's body to attack them
  until it is stopped by Elise. She reveals that her acquaintance with
  Lorraine is decades old, because she previously performed the same
  service on Josh when he was eight years old (he was terrorized by the
  parasitic spirit of an old woman). Josh also possesses the ability to
  astral project, and Dalton inherited this trait from him. Elise tells
  Josh that the only way to rescue Dalton is to go into the Further.
Elise puts Josh in a trance and he is able to project himself to their
  previous house. He goes to the attic and finds a red door, but is
  attacked by the mysterious figure that attacked Renai. After defeating
  him, Josh enters the Demon's lair, where Josh finds Dalton chained to
  the floor. After a tearful reunion, Josh frees him, but they are
  caught by the demon. Josh tries to fight it, but they are forced to
  flee with the demon in pursuit. Returning through the red door, Josh
  confronts the old woman that haunted him as a child. The old woman
  dissolves into darkness after Josh shouts at it to leave him alone.
  When Josh and Dalton return to their bodies they wake up in their new
  home and the spirits disappear.
As they celebrate the end of their ordeal, Elise starts packing her
  equipment
with Josh, when she senses that something is wrong (she notices Josh's
  hands look old and dirty, similar to the old woman's), and proceeds to
  take a photo of Josh. Josh goes into a violent rage, as he doesn't
  like to have his picture taken and strangles Elise to death. Renai is
  horrified when she discovers Elise's dead body and searches for Josh
  to inform him of her sudden death. Renai picks up the camera and sees
  that the image Elise took of Josh is the old woman that haunted him as
  a child, implying that Josh has been possessed. Josh, suddenly appears
  behind her, and she turns around and gasps.


